# could not access WakefulBroadcastReceiver that is in present in external library

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I am doing a push notification using GCM that is written in an SDK,developer needs to add my SDK as library project ,my SDK uses the context from the developer and creates Registeration Id ,but when i push from an server using the ID i could not receive any notification in fact my receiver class is not invoked

Manifest file in SDK has

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.mysdk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

permission has

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <permission
    android:name="com.mysdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mysdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Manifest in app that has my SDK as library file

```
      <receiver
        android:name="com.mysdk.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.mysdk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.mysdk.GcmIntentService" />
```

permission has

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.mysdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mysdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

can any one suggest what went wrong ,May be is this possible ,i.e. sending notification from 
SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that uses your SDK shouldn't use `com.mysdk` for the GCM permissions and for the category of the broadcast receiver intent-filter. Instead it should use its own package name.

Below I marked the changes you should make in your app's manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.mysdk.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="CHANGE_TO_YOUR_APPS_PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.mysdk.GcmIntentService" />

<permission android:name="CHANGE_TO_YOUR_APPS_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="CHANGE_TO_YOUR_APPS_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran ,you have saved my head !!